# Sql Query issue and error regarding groupby cause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the total number of Projects in every year. and also how many projects are active, how many of them are canceled.

I tried to group by cause for PRojects dates so we have a total number of project in every year but I am not sure where to start and what to do

```
Select  ts.Id as projectid ,
    --a.ParentObjectId,
    ts.RequestName as ProjectDates,
    ts.Type,
    ts.Category,
    ts.SubType,
    ts.status as projectstatus,
    Count (ts.ReceptionDate),
    cast (ts.ReceptionDate as  Date) as ReceptionDate,

from [rpt].[TransmissionServicesRpt] ts  
left join [dbo].[AuditHistory] a on a.ParentObjectId = ts.Id
Left join [dbo].[User] u on a.CreatedById = u.id
Group by ts.id, ts.ReceptionDate
```

```
+ -------------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| New Projects | Active | Cancelled | Terminated | Inactive | Carried Forward |
+ -------------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 2013         |     32 |       45  |          4 |       11 |              30 |
| 2014         |     45 |       75  |         17 |       14 |              44 |
| 2015         |     46 |       90  |         25 |       21 |              44 |
| 2016         |     30 |       74  |         27 |       10 |              37 |
| 2017         |     82 |      119  |         11 |       26 |              82 |
| 2018         |     86 |      168  |         29 |       24 |             115 |
| 2019         |     23 |      138  |          9 |        4 |             125 |
+ -------------+--------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the data that you are starting with.  How do you define active?  Cancelled?  And so on?

Comment: Based on the table with the desired results, you want to group by the YEAR column. Then use [**conditional aggregation**](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+conditional+aggregation) to get the sums for each of the other columns. I'd write some SQL in an answer, but we need to know more about your data to be able to do that.

Comment: ProjectId  Status          Date
     1589 Active         8/29/2018
     1566 Inactive 4/17/2018
     1042 Cancelled 1/6/2014
     1374 Completed 1/20/2015
     1543 Completed 8/4/2014
     1065 Cancelled 7/15/2014
     1397 Completed 10/1/2012
     1520 Inactive         4/13/2017
     1420 Completed 1/1/2015
     1443 Completed 1/1/2015
     1048 Cancelled 10/16/2014
     1002 Active         2/6/2017
     1357 Completed 1/19/2017
     1606 Active         11/6/2018

Comment: From Project Status

Comment: I can't read that. Use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57312051/edit) on the question and add it to the bottom of the question. Use a `<pre>` block to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one result row per year. So group by year. You get it via `YEAR` or `DATEPART`. Then count conditionally:

```
select
  year(receptiondate) as year,
  count(*) as total,
  count(case when status = 'Active' then 1 end) as active,
  count(case when status = 'Cancelled' then 1 end) as cancelled,
  count(case when status = 'Terminated' then 1 end) as terminated,
  count(case when status = 'Inactive' then 1 end) as inactive,
  count(case when status = 'Carried Forward' then 1 end) as carried_forward
from rpt.transmissionservicesrpt
group by year(receptiondate)
order by year(receptiondate);
```

Comment: Hey, could you help me with one more question? If I wanted to find carry on a project from 2013 to 2014 for example project id from reception date 2013 = project id and reception date 2014 then display carry forward projects. the number project was continued form 2013 to 2014. please

Comment: @WonderWoman: That's a bit more complicated, because while you want to show a result row per year, each year's row shall know about  the year following. I suggest you make this a new request.